# Python List to its exact string representation

Tags: python

I want to convert a python list to its exact string representation.

Example:

```
L = ['L','O','L',True]
```

Desired string representation:

```
"['L','O','L',true]"
```

Reason: I need to embed that string inside a javascript snippet. Any ideas on how i can do this effectively ?

Comment: do you have nested lists?

Comment: Yes, there are lists within that list...

Comment: JSON-encode it if you want to pass it to Javascript.

Comment: What's wrong with `repr(L)`?

Comment: `str(L)` won't do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass values to Javascript, JSON-encode them:

```
import json
js = 'var l = %s;' % json.dumps(L)
```

Comment: This will also convert `True` to `true`, `None` to `null`, etc., so this is not the "exact string representation" of the list, but it might be better suited for use in JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pprint
a = [[1,2],3,4,[5,6,[7]]]
b = pprint.pformat(a)
print(a)
```

this works as well, but yeah json might be better for js